# Using CUDA in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: cuda

Starting development of CUDA-based tools on Ubuntu, and tried to install/use the SDK. However, deviceQuery gives

```
CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

For reference:

```
# nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Oct_18_17:35:10_PDT_2011
Cuda compilation tools, release 4.1, V0.2.1221

# cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  280.13  Wed Jul 27 16:53:56 PDT 2011
GCC version:  gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
```

I obtain similar errors with other tools (namely Theano's gpu utilities).

Comment: The 280.13 driver is not compatible with their latest 4.1 beta toolkit. You will need to install the 290.xx driver or use cuda 4.0

Answer (score 3):

The CUDA runtime must match the driver, i.e the kernel module. You seem to have driver version 280.13 that is only compatible with the 4.0 runtime. Either downgrade the runtime or upgrade the driver/kernel module: [dev driver for 4.1 (285.05.32)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/drivers/devdriver_4.1_linux_64_285.05.32.run)

Answer (score 0):

also you should take a look at gcc.
4.6.* may cause problems
use 4.4 alongside 4.6 (update-alternatives)